# Why is return skipping the value produced in my ternary operator?

Tags: ruby, operator-keyword, ternary

I have this code:

```
def FirstFactorial(num)

  num == 0 ? 1 : num * FirstFactorial(num - 1)
  return num

end
```

however, the result keeps returning the original argument. How can I return the result created by my ternary operator?

Comment: You have too many equals signs..   `num = 0 ? 1 : num....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns the argument because you told to do so. Try this.

```
def FirstFactorial(num)

  return (num == 0 ? 1 : num * FirstFactorial(num - 1))

end
```

Comment: Thank you! I kept putting the operator in brackets instead of parenthesis.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept the answer if it solved the issue. And remember, drink less coffee, sleep more :-P

Comment: :P I was going to but it said I had to wait at least 12 minutes.. boo! 5 minutes now :)

Answer (score 2):

Just to add as succint an answer as possible for posterity's sake:

Ruby uses implicit returns on the last line of your method declaration.

Thus:

```
def FirstFactorial(num)

  num == 0 ? 1 : num * FirstFactorial(num - 1)

end
```

Comment: return ought to be ashamed of itself!

Comment: Ah! Simplicity over all else, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set num equal to the result of the ternary operator. Or just return it as in Elyasin's answer.

```
def FirstFactorial(num)

  num = num == 0 ? 1 : num * FirstFactorial(num - 1)
  return num

end
```

Edit:
Although, remember that in ruby the result of the last line is returned, so you could just say:

```
def FirstFactorial(num)

  num == 0 ? 1 : num * FirstFactorial(num - 1)

end
```